# Writing list of lists properly to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have data which looks like below:

```
(['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'], ['string5'], ['string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10', 'string11', 'string12']
```

which is three lists within a list.

What I am trying to do, is to write...

1. All three lists in a row
2. The strings as columns, something like:

   ```
   string1 | string2 | string3 | string4 | string5 | string6 | string7 | ...
   ```

and so on.

I have tried:

```
with open('output-file.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in rows_to_write:
        writer.writerows(row)
```

but afterwards the output looks like:

```
string1 | string2 | string3 | string4
string5 |
string6 | string7 | ...
```

How can I manage to put the two following rows into the first row?

Comment: Search for "flatten list python".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lutz Horn is right.
You need to flatten the list before writing to csv.
One way to do it would be like this:

```
row = []
for x in (['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'], ['string5'], ['string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10', 'string11', 'string12']):
    row = row + x
```

Comment: Did not recognize Lutz Horn's comment. But thank you both! Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine the list first before writing, not sure if that is what you want.

```
listall = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[4, 5, 6]]
listmerge = []
for row in listall:
    listmerge = listmerge+row
print listmerge

with open('output-file.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for row in listmerge:
        writer.writerows(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to convert it into a single list and then use your csv writer code.

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'], ['string5'], ['string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10', 'string11', 'string12']

_l = [k for sublist in l for k in sublist]

with open('output_file.csv','w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(_l)
```

Now the output_file.csv looks like
`string1|string2|string3|string4|string5|string6|string7|string8|string9|string10|string11|string12`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a single row, you could take the following approach:

```
from itertools import chain

data = (['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'], ['string5'], ['string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10', 'string11', 'string12'])

with open('output-file.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(list(chain.from_iterable(data)))
```

Giving you your output csv as follows:

```
string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6,string7,string8,string9,string10,string11,string12
```

If you want to change the csv delimiter to `|`, you could use:

```
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
import csv

mainList = (['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'], ['string5'], ['string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10', 'string11', 'string12'])

with open('eggs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    csv_writer.writerow([val for subList in mainList for val in subList])
```